# Generate multiple outputs using Babel and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I would like to transpile my Javascript application into two different Javascript files:
1rst one for **legacy browsers**
2nd one for **Modern browsers**
With the plan of having a smaller build for modern mobile browsers whilst still supporting older legacy desktop browsers.

The *babel-cli* allows for a preset so I can set it to "env", but there does not appear to be a way of setting target browsers outside of the .*babelrc* which would mean having to change the *.babelrc* file.

*Webpack* allows use of the *babel-loader* to specify the target browsers, but there doesn't appear to be a way of using it twice for different browser targets on env.

Is there any way of simply achieving what I need?

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way of doing it myself, not sure if it is the most elegant solution, but it works. The solution uses webpack-merge to have multiple webpack configs. Here are the test project files ("npm run buildlegacy", and "npm run buildios" do the heavy lifting afterwards in this test example:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testbabel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "buildios": "webpack --config ./ios.config.js",
    "buildlegacy": "webpack --config ./legacy.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

base.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app:'./src/app.js'
    }
};
```

ios.config.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./base.config.js');

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'ios11.bundle.js',
      },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    "presets": [
                        ["env", 
                            {
                                "targets": {
                                "browsers": ["ios_saf 11"]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

legacy.config.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./base.config.js');

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'legacy.bundle.js',
      },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    "presets": [
                        ["env", 
                            {
                                "targets": {
                                "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "ie 8"]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: One file: `module.exports = [iosConfig, legacyConfig]`